# How can make changes to my smb.conf file go live without a reboot?

Tags: samba, command-line-interface, mask

On our Centos 7 server, I added `create mask = 770` to my `smb.conf` in order to force permissions on the files our Windows users store in a directory.  Then from the command line, I entered the following:

```
# systemctl restart smb.service

# systemctl restart nmb.service
```

...but the files were not saved with the right permissions.  They were saved correctly after a reboot.  So what happened in the reboot that (maybe) I could have done from the command line?

Here's the section of the smb.conf:

```
[image-storage]
     comment = archived image location
     path = /our/samba/path/to/image_storage
     valid users = @NameOfOurGroup
     create mask = 770
     browsable = yes
     writable = yes
     guest ok = no
     force user = imagestore
```

Answer (score 18):

Restarting just the service seems like an improvement on rebooting.  Even better still is to make use of the config reload that comes with many linux services, including Samba. This feature is often accessed with a SIGHUP signal or via a control program.

Use *smbcontrol* ([man page](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smbcontrol.1.html)) to reload the config with the lowest downtime and lowest-possible impact on services already using your shares.  So, just run this:

```
smbcontrol smbd reload-config
```

Comment: I had added a new share to the `smb.conf` and tried the command you wrote (prefixed with `sudo`). Unfortunately, the new share did not appear. I had to restart the service, then it appeared.

Comment: Without reboot it works but with `rm -R /var/cache/samba/*` like @Tox said here https://askubuntu.com/a/872460/972235

Answer (score 1):

You have the name of the service wrong.  Try:

```
# systemctl restart smb.service
# systemctl restart nmb.service
```

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect this.  This also fails in exactly the same way.  Restarting samba does not seem to affect the image_storage directory.

Comment: my system doesn't even know smb.service or nmb.service but still it has a smb.conf file and reachable shares

Comment: on my system it is actually `systemctl restart smbd.service` and `systemctl restart nmbd.service`  if you don't know the name of the service try :  `systemctl | grep mb` and you may find it

Comment: be sure you want to restart the smb service before using this answer, it will kick connected users. Better to use `smbcontrol smbd reload-config` if you just want to reload new shares or update config.

Answer (score 1):

Samba creates a child processes for each connected user. According to the manual the parent process monitors the config file and automatically reloads it if it changes. So your changes are acted on almost instantly without your doing anything, however the changes are not propagated to the current crop of child processes.

Any new user mounting shares will see your changes.

If you wish to see them

- Dismount all your samba shares from your windows machine. Your child process on the samba server will die when your last share is unmounted. Mounting a drive creates a new child process with the new settings
- Or kill your samba child process.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
# chcon -Rt samba_share_t /our/samba/path/to/image_storage
```

fixed the issue without a reboot.  As it was explained to me, this line informs SELinux that the share exists.

Answer (score 0):

***This answer was by far the best one for me:***
Be sure you want to restart the smb service before using this answer, it will kick connected users. Better to use **smbcontrol smbd reload-config** if you just want to reload new shares or update config. –
PrestonDocks
Jan 8, 2022 at 0:52

Comment: I used the command **`smbcontrol smbd reload-config`** after I added a new share to a server, and I didn't want to have to restart the server, which would have disconnected many users who were using other shares, interrupting their work _badly_!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).